# Android CheckBox isChecked() or editing SharedPreferences causing forced close

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, ischecked

I'm writing a flash card app in Android, and I tried to add the ability to add a word to a review list by having a checkbox. When the user goes to the next word, I see whether the checkbox is checked. If it is, I add the word to the review list, and if it isn't, I remove the word. When I tested it on my phone and the emulator, I got a forced close every time I try  to go to the next word or to the home page when the checkbox is checked. I don't know what's causing the error because in the LogCat page, it doesn't show the line number or what error happened.

I can flip through the words without a problem when I don't have them checked; checking it and going to another word is what causes a problem, so I'm guessing it has to do with the SharedPreferences.

Here are the important methods I have:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
            //other code
    reviewCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.reviewCheckBox);
    prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();
    reviewCards = prefs.getAll().keySet();
}
public void home(View v)
{
    if (flashCardPage.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        if (reviewCheckBox.isChecked())
            reviewCards.add(currentCard.getTerm());
        else
            reviewCards.remove(currentCard.getTerm());

        updateReviewCards();
    }
    //other code
}
public void nextWord(View v)
{
    currentPosition++;

    if (currentPosition == flashCards.size())
    {
        home(wordTV);
    }
    else
    {
        if (reviewCheckBox.isChecked())
            reviewCards.add(currentCard.getTerm());
        else
            reviewCards.remove(currentCard.getTerm());

        //other code

        if (reviewCards.contains(currentCard.getTerm()))
            reviewCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        else
            reviewCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    }
}

public void previousWord(View v)
{
    if (currentPosition > 0)
    {
        if (reviewCheckBox.isChecked())
            reviewCards.add(currentCard.getTerm());
        else
            reviewCards.remove(currentCard.getTerm());

        //other code

        if (reviewCards.contains(currentCard.getTerm()))
            reviewCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        else
            reviewCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    }
}
public void updateReviewCards()
{
    editor.clear();

    for (String card : reviewCards)
        editor.putString(card, card);

    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: This code is so out of context that it is really difficult to answer. Are you sure the logcat doesn't display anything? One thing you can do to help debug is add your own log entries at various parts of your code. For example, ing updateReviewCards, you can add the line `Log.i("update", "update completed");`

Comment: I think I found out the problem. When I hover over keySet(), it says the set does not support adding.  Sorry the code and/or my question is hard to understand.  I didn't want to include the parts that are irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set returned by `getPreferences().getAll().keySet()` does not support adding.